# How to test Cassandra Database using Robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I need to connect to Cassandra Database and Query from there.
I want to know, is there any exist database library for Cassandra in Robot Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no, there isn't such.

One of the active (and good) Cassandra drivers for Python is from a company called DataStax, here is its repo - https://github.com/datastax/python-driver. Have in mind it has some peculiarities getting installed and running in the various OSes.
But as it does not (regretfully) adhere to [Python Database API](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DatabaseInterfaces), so you cannot just install it and straight ahead use by RF's DatabaseLibrary.

You could/should create your own library wrapping the driver calls (which shouldn't be that hard...).